# Forge Revit pricing

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am going to run a Revit add-in in forge. When I run it locally it takes 20 sec for Revit to startup than my add-in runs for one sec. My question is that will I pay for the Revit startup time in addition to the add-in execution time in Forge? Will I pay 21 unit or just one?

Answer (score 0):

The time you are charged for includes:

- download time of input files
- running time of executables on the server (e.g. starting up Revit Core Console and running your app bundle code)
- upload time of results

i.e. the time between when the download of the inputs started till the upload of the results finished

See https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/estimate-design-automation-costs

Depending on your workflow there are different ways to reduce the amount of time needed:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/optimize-design-automation-process 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/open-network-preview